# Sending/receiving string from PHP to Python

Tags: php, python

I'm running two Python scripts from my PHP code. To send the values to the scripts I'm doing:

```
$output1 = shell_exec('python /path/to/my/script1.py '.$name);
$output1 = explode(',', $output1);
```

and then I'm doing:

```
$output2 = shell_exec('python /path/to/my/script2.py '.$output1[0]);
$output2 = explode(',', $output2);
```

`$output1` receives the return from the python script correctly but `script2.py` is returning me a wrong value. Manually setting that value of `$output1[0]` directly on `script2.py` gives me a correct value so the problem is not the script.

I already did a `echo var_dump($output1);` and it's giving me a correct `$output1[0]`, so the problem is neither the value coming from `$output1`.

Any clues?

Edit1: the value of `$output1[0]` is a string with white spaces ("Green Day").

Edit2: seems like it's passing just the word "Green". When I pass a string that has a white space, only the first word is passed. That doesn't make sense since I'm exploding by ',' and when I echo the `$output1` it shows me the correct string with the white space included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem so I'll answer here in case someone has the same problem.

The function `shell_exec` works like this:

```
$var = shell_exec('python path/to/your/python/script.py '.$var1.' '.$var2. ...);
```

The arguments you wanna pass to your python script MUST be separated by a white space, that's how python will interpret the multi variables you are sending.

The string "Green Day" has a white space within it, so it was like sending

```
$var = shell_exec('python path/to/your/python/script.py Green Day');
```

So when I'd do `sys.argv[1]` in Python, it would get only "Green" cause "Day" would be the "second" parameter.

So just loop through your `sys.argv` in Python and concatenate the strings like this:

```
string = ''
for word in sys.argv[1:]:
    string += word + ' '
```

Comment: Have you tried quoting your parameters? `"Green Day"` (repr: `'"Green Day"'`)

Comment: I'm not sending the "raw string", the string is contained in $var1. The solution I give above works well.

Comment: if, some times, you want to parse more complex arguments (even arguments having quotes) read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/twistylittlepassagesallalike/archive/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-arguments-the-wrong-way.aspx?Redirected=true)